# fp-ts filterWithIndex "index signatures are incompatible"

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

Learning typescript via `fp-ts` leads me to trouble.

I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'Record<string, number>' is not assignable to type 'Timestamps'.
> Index signatures are incompatible.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Timestamp'.(2322)

Code below:

```
import * as R from "fp-ts/dist/esm/Record";

interface Timestamp {
  date: number
  id: string
}

interface Timestamps {
  [key: string]: Timestamp
}

const MyFunction = (dates: Timestamps): Timestamps => {
    const predicate = (s: string, v: number) => s === "date" && v > 0 // 0 milliseconds
    return R.filterWithIndex(predicate)(dates)
}
```

What should i change for my code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You predicate needs to operate on `Timestamp`s, not `number`s

```js
const predicate = (s: string, v: Timestamp) =>
  s === "date" && v.date > 0
```